# Rails shuts down server on its own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

**UPDATE** I abandoned this app for now, moved on to other authentication gems that seemed a bit simpler to me. Please feel free to clarify the situation if you can answer anyway. Thanks !

I'm trying to make a simple app using Ruby on Rails and using the 'authlogic' gem. The problem arises when I try to save a new user (register). The server doesn't respond anymore and rails posts this inside the project console:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-20 14:39:03 
+0200Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"Gk5wycJaDjsKbZ3z5MKtFJc9ITsLMp2EXnFLYlHOOgE=", 
"user"=>{"username"=>"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "email"=>"aaaaaaaaa@aaaaa.aa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

After this shows up in the console the server does not respond until starting it manually again. Then it actually refreshes on its own, shows the index page and submits user data for registration. At least I guess it saves the data because the browser asks me if I want to save the password for the username entered. I don't know what to think about the problem when this is the only thing it posts before going offline, without any error or warning signs. My guess is that I'm missing something pretty trivial since I'm a total noob at Rails. Anyway, here's some code:

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def index

 end

 def new  
    @user = User.new  
 end  

def create  
  @user = User.new(user_params)  
  if @user.save  
    flash[:notice] = "Registration successful."  
    redirect_to root_path
  else  
    render 'new'  
  end  
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :email, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

The routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users

  root 'articles#index'
end
```

The form template:

```
<%= form_for @user do |form| %>  
<ul style="list-style-type: none; padding:0px;  ">  
  <li>  
    <%= form.label :username, "Username" %><br />  
    <%= form.text_field :username %><br />    
  </li>  
  <li>  
    <%= form.label :email, "E-mail" %><br />    
    <%= form.text_field :email %><br />    
  </li>  
  <li>  
    <%= form.label :password, "Password" %><br />    
    <%= form.password_field :password %><br />    
  </li>  
  <li>  
    <%= form.label :password_confirmation, "Password confirmation" %><br />    
    <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation %><br />  
  </li>  
  <li>  
    <%= form.submit %> 
  </li>  
</ul>  
<% end %>
```

There's an error message output part in the template file, but I don't think it has something to do with my problem, it works properly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Paste the error `log`

Comment: I pasted the only thing that is shown at the top of the post. That's kind of what I find the most confusing, no errors or warning messages to be seen directly from the log.

Comment: please try to create user in console once.

Comment: Also check if your project has any `sleep` or `debugger` commands, that might freeze the server

Comment: No, it does not. It was made as a default Rails project in Aptana. The controllers and models were generated over the console and I didn't use anything that I haven't run into already. Except for the authlogic gem of course. Maybe the best bet would be to try and remake the entire project step by step to see if that fixes anything. Other than that, I have absolutely no idea on what to do with this.